# GTK+3 Application running on macOS does not have the same keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, homebrew

I am running a Gtk+3 application on macOS x using brew. The application works fine except for the keyboard shortcuts.

The keyboard shortcuts have a different mapping than the "standard" Mac keyboard shortcuts. It seems to me to be a standard Linux mapping.

For example:

Copy is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
Paste is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Is there a way to change the keyboard mapping for a Gtk+3 application running on Mac to be similar to other Mac applications?

So far I was searching for similar or related questions here and on related websites: found some questions but not good answers:

https://superuser.com/questions/634020/gnome-3-copy-paste-with-a-mac-keyboard

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far?

Comment: I read somewhere that I can add a settings.ini file that will be loaded by gtk. But I don't know where to put the file, I don't know how to check if the application is respecting the settings files, I don't know what to put in the settings.ini to fix the keyboard mapping.